# Why are many ports of languages to .net prefixed with 'Iron'?

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

Was discussing over lunch why several ports of languages to the .net framework are prefixed with 'Iron'.

e.g.

- IronPython
- IronRuby
- IronLisp
- IronScheme
- IronPHP

Anyone out there know?

(language list sourced from http://www.dotnetpowered.com/languages.aspx)

Comment: There is also IronJS, and what else...? :)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

IronPython came first and the rest followed. As for why IronPython is called IronPython, Jim Hugunin goes into that in [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL10/) (at about 14:00). He says it was partly to avoid calling it Language.NET or Language#, and the idea is that Iron languages are:

- True language implementations

  - True to the language
  - True to the community
  - True to the experience
  - Excellent performance
- Great integration with .NET

  - Easy to use .NET libraries
  - Easy to use other .NET languages
  - Easy to use in .NET hosts
  - Easy to use with .NET tools

And a slightly specious acronym explanation, which came after the name:

**I**mplementation **R**unning **O**n .**N**ET.

Answer (score 32):

From the creator of IronPython Jim Hugunin

http://port25.technet.com/archive/2006/06/01/2565.aspx

> I'll give you the story, but I'll give
>   you the short version 'cause it's not
>   very good.
>
> At the time, I had a consulting
>   company called "Want of a Nail
>   Software". "Want of a Nail" is based
>   on a children's poem. It's about the
>   importance of small things. I've
>   always kind of believed in the
>   importance of small things. Part of
>   the story of IronPython's actual
>   performance is it wasn't one big thing
>   - Everybody wants to know "What was the one big thing?" There were some
>   big things, but most of it was all the
>   small things - paying attention to
>   performance in every place.
>
> So, that was the consulting company
>   and "Iron" seemed to match.
>
> There were some obvious names:
>   Python.Net, Python#, nPython - All of
>   those were taken. All of the URLs for
>   those were registered.
>
> I didn't want to reuse any of those
>   names, so "Iron" was just kind of a
>   name that appealed to me at a visceral
>   level - I like the feeling of
>   "IronPython".
>
> There's a little bit of "Iron Chef" in
>   it, although I'm always reluctant to
>   admit that.

Comment: What is "Iron Chef"?

Answer (score 18):

Iron is strong  :)

I have no idea!

I am the author of IronScheme, and I am just going along with the marketing wave  :P

Comment: Suppose the available choices were IronScheme or Scheme# ;-)

Comment: Hey, I think I'm going to invent a language called Y.  :-)

Comment: Quick, someone create a language called "Ning" ;)

Comment: Scheme# is taken, sorry, it really hard to find a scheme name nowadays, with the odd 150 implementations :)

Answer (score 5):

All are [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=FAQ) followers, the question is, where did [IronPython originate? (video)](http://port25.technet.com/archive/2006/06/01/2565.aspx)

> Meet Jim Huginin creator of Jython and the brains behind IronPython...

As the video is no longer (Aug 2010) available, I'll [include a quote](http://vlasenko.org/2008/10/):

*IronPython* is an implementation of the Python programming language, targeting the .NET Framework and Mono, created by Jim Hugunin. Today Jim on his session “Deep Dive: Dynamic Languages in Microsoft .NET” has explained the Iron nature.
It is the acronim from the “
**I**mplementation 
**r**unning **o**n .**N**et”.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a particular reason.  More so that the first one was named Iron (IronPython I believe) and the others followed suit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the element some answers spring to mind. The positive one first: It's easy to form alloys of iron, often with superior properties.

There's also some negative connotations, draw your own conclusions: Iron rusts very easily

Comment: Not to mention it's quite brittle :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the video Pumping Iron (found on Channel9) it stands for **I**t **R**uns **O**n .**N**et, not **I**mplementation **R**unning **O**n .**N**ET.

Answer (score 0):

I have no supporting evidence whatsoever but I always thought that the Iron Cobra monster from Dungeons and Dragons must have had some influence on the naming of IronPython.